# What is the best way to define log TAG constant in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, constants

I'm creating my first Kotlin classes in my Android application. Usually for logging purposes I have a constant with name `TAG`. What I would do in Java is:

```
private static final String TAG = MyClass.class.getSimpleName();
```

I know that in Kotlin classes I can create `TAG` using this way:

```
private val TAG = MyClass::class.java.simpleName
```

This is OK for projects that use Java and Kotlin but what if I start a new project that is only in Kotlin? How can I define there `TAG` constant? Is there more Kotlin way where I don't have this strange construction `class.java.simpleName`?

Comment: Using `simpleName` is [risky](https://medium.com/@elye.project/the-danger-of-using-class-getsimplename-as-tag-for-fragment-5cdf3a35bfe2) if class name is obfuscated.

Comment: Risky? To say the least!  It ALWAYS crashes my apps when done this way.

Comment: private val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName;

Comment: check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=buhk5TRX_rw&t=3s starting at 7:24

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In general constants are all caps (ex. FOO) and located in the [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects):

```
class MyClass {
    companion object {
        public const val FOO = 1

    }
}
```

and to define the TAG field you can use:

```
private val TAG = MyClass::class.qualifiedName
```

Comment: MyClass::class.qualifiedName return String, so It showing err with const ... what to do?

Comment: @EnamulHaque in the TAG val definition I don't use const

Comment: @EnamulHaque `const` values have to be compile time constants. As Kotlin has nothing like `nameof` it can't guarantee that that statement always will have the same value. Also, as Gabriele Mariotti said, `const` wasn't used in the answer.

Comment: Hmm, according to Android Studio's warnings, `MyClass::class.qualifiedName` requires reflection, which greatly increases the complexity of the application and requires an additional jar file.  Is there a simpler way to do this oh-so-common task?

Comment: @ScottBiggs how about using `MyClass::class.java.simpleName` ?

Comment: Is there a good reference to read about how using reflection increases application complexity? (I didn't see anything about that here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html)

Comment: We use @ScottBiggs approach `MyClass::class.java.simpleName` at my company.

Answer (score 85):

This extension allows us to use TAG in any class

```
val Any.TAG: String
    get() {
        val tag = javaClass.simpleName
        return if (tag.length <= 23) tag else tag.substring(0, 23)
    }

//usage
Log.e(TAG,"some value")
```

It it also validated to work as an Android valid Log tag.

Comment: Thanks, I use it all the time!

Comment: won't work for anonymous inner class, great otherwise

Comment: I'm new to kotlin, so a honest question: are there any downsides to this (except the anonymous inner class)? It seems like the best answer, because i think thats what kotlin extensions are for..

Comment: This is a great answer, but the length check is not needed if your minSDK is 24 or higher as there is no longer a tag length restriction.

Comment: If I have a class with 30 tags, does it mean I will instantiate TAG 30 times at runtime?

Or will it only instantiate one tag and reference it?

Comment: @RahulTiwari did you find a solution for anonymous inner classes?

Comment: Just found the anonymous solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/55915831/704836

Comment: make it inline val

Comment: Where does this go? What's an extension?

Comment: Kotlin is like a weapon, you should know which button to turn ON

Comment: Why can't this be part of the default Kotlin language design?

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: This solution can be misleading in certain scenarios, if you for example log inside a coroutine like viewmodelScope.launch(), the extension function will get the tag name from the Coroutine and not from the desired class.

Answer (score 22):

Commonly suggested approach of using the `companion object` generates extra `static final` instance of a companion class and thus is bad performance and memory-wise.

### The best way (IMHO)

Define a log tag as a top-level constant, thus only extra class is generated (`MyClassKt`), but compared to `companion object` there will be no `static final` instance of it (and no instance whatsoever):

```
private const val TAG = "MyLogTag"

class MyClass {

    fun logMe() {
        Log.w(TAG, "Message")
    }
}
```

### Another option

Use a normal `val`. Though this looks unusual to see a log tag not as an all-uppercase constant, this will not generate any classes and has least overhead.

```
class MyClass {

    private val tag = "myLogTag"

    fun logMe() {
        Log.w(tag, "Message")
    }
}
```

Comment: why isn't this the most upvoted answer? Since I don't think you will use TAGs outside the class it doesn't need to be in a companion class. The next question is are both options posted here equally good regarding memory consumption, performance, etc.?

Comment: I hate to say that this is the best solution I've seen (and the one I've been using for a few years).  But you have to be very careful that you spell the `tag` variable correctly--I've spent considerable time wondering why logs weren't found in the filter because the `tag` was misspelled.  Why is making a simple constant so difficult?

Answer (score 19):

I Like `TAG` to be an extension function [as suggested by Fredy Mederos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53510106/1529129).

extending his answer to support anonymous classes :

```
 /**
 * extension function to provide TAG value
 */
val Any.TAG: String
    get() {
        return if (!javaClass.isAnonymousClass) {
            val name = javaClass.simpleName
            if (name.length <= 23) name else name.substring(0, 23)// first 23 chars
        } else {
            val name = javaClass.name
            if (name.length <= 23) name else name.substring(name.length - 23, name.length)// last 23 chars
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good answer, but as of API 24, there is no length restriction, so if your app's min SDK is 24+, you can do away with the length checks.

Comment: I like this solution and tried it in a current project, but for some reason in some classes it wouldn't resolve the reference in Android Studio...and others it would work. Strange

Comment: @szaske are those inner classes?

Comment: @RahulTiwari And what if it is called in a coroutine?

Comment: @asclepix why does that make any difference?

Comment: @RahulTiwari using a simple `Log.w(TAG, "Message")` it prints `StandaloneCoroutine` as TAG. I should remember to use something like `Log.w(this@MainActivity.TTAG, "Message")`, isn't it?

Comment: yes if you need host activity/class name as tag. otherwise whatever is the name of anonymous class is (StandaloneCoroutine in your case)  will get print

Answer (score 15):

In Kotlin you could create an extension, and call tag as a method call instead. This would mean you'd never have to define it inside each class, we can construct it dynamically each time we call the method:

```
inline fun <reified T> T.TAG(): String = T::class.java.simpleName
```

Comment: simpleName is not good solution when build is obfuscated e.g. MyActivity may become M and you will see M everywhere in the log. It fails in scenarios like pre-releases build, where build is release type but we still want to capture logs!

Answer (score 15):

The best way to log (imho) is using Timber:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber

But if you don't want to use library then

TAG can be defined as an inlined extension property (e.g. in `Extensions.kt`):

```
inline val <reified T> T.TAG: String
    get() = T::class.java.simpleName
```

Some more extensions to not to write TAG all the time in `Log.d(TAG, "")`:

```
inline fun <reified T> T.logv(message: String) = Log.v(TAG, message)
inline fun <reified T> T.logi(message: String) = Log.i(TAG, message)
inline fun <reified T> T.logw(message: String) = Log.w(TAG, message)
inline fun <reified T> T.logd(message: String) = Log.d(TAG, message)
inline fun <reified T> T.loge(message: String) = Log.e(TAG, message)
```

And then you can use them in any class:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    logd("Activity created")
}
```

Comment: Павел, how do you want to use Timber?

Comment: @CoolMind Just set it up in applications `onCreate() { if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree()) }` and then in any class just use `Timber.d("msg")` without need for explicit LOG_TAG

Comment: Ah, thanks, I understood. I looked for `TAG`, Timber has already been added.

Comment: does Kotlin also have the char limit for tags that the old java Log class had?

Comment: @BrillPappin afaik, tag length limit is related to android version, not to the language. According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#isLoggable(java.lang.String,%20int)) there is no limit since api24, but I've found that problem [may appear on versions above 24](https://github.com/mvysny/slf4j-handroid/issues/2)

Comment: @PavelBerdnikov yes, it seems it should handle it automatically now. My guess on your issue is you may have libraries built on older versions.

Comment: Can I change this TAG name for another one like TAGClass? How does it work?
Why in usage in fragment instead of T there is used specific name of the fragment? In my usage it is:
Timber.d("$TAGClass here usage TAG generic").

Comment: It logs CoroutineScope, so it doesn't takes main class name by default, how to improve it :)

Answer (score 11):

Simply doing the following worked for me.

```
private val TAG = this::class.java.simpleName
```

Comment: is this piece of code safe to be used inside a `companion object`?

Comment: you would need kotlin-reflect.jar

Answer (score 6):

You can define your `TAG` by `@JvmField` as below:

```
companion object {
    @JvmField val TAG: String = MyClass::class.java.simpleName
}
```

For more details, you can read this article : [Kotlin's hidden costs](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/exploring-kotlins-hidden-costs-part-1-fbb9935d9b62)

Comment: Your source says this: "In fact, this annotation has been created solely for Java compatibility reasons and I would definitely not recommend to clutter your beautiful Kotlin code with an obscure interop annotation". Why do you recommend using @JvmField then?

Answer (score 4):

I created some Log extension functions to avoid declaring the log tag as we did in Java (maybe less performant, but given that we are talking about logging this should be acceptable IMO). The approach uses reified type parameters and other Kotlin goodies to retrieve the class simple name. Here is a basic example:

```
inline fun <reified T> T.logi(message: String) =
   Log.i(T::class.java.simpleName, message)
```

You can find a more elaborated gist [here](https://gist.github.com/paolop/0bd59e49b33d18d6089fb1bf5488e212)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I don't see why continue to mimic the Java approach

Answer (score 2):

I'm creating the constant as a companion object:

```
companion object {
    val TAG = "SOME_TAG_VALUE"
}
```

Then, I can use it like this:

```
MyClass.TAG
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer with `Kotlin 1.2.20`

```
class MyClass {
    companion object {

        @JvmField
        public val FOO = 1
    }
}
```

uses

```
MyClass.FOO
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare of TAG variable with `val`

```
class YourClass {
   companion object {
      //if use java and kotlin both in project
      //private val TAG = MyClass::class.java.simpleName

      //if use only kotlin in project
      private val TAG = YourClass::class.simpleName
   }
}
```

Use the variable like

```
Log.d(YourClass.TAG, "Your message");
//or 
Log.e(TAG, "Your message");
```

Comment: If you don't use `::class.java.simpleName`, you have to include `kotlin-reflect.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way which is more "copy-paste"-able, since it doesn't require you to type the name of your class:

```
package com.stackoverflow.mypackage

class MyClass
{
    companion object {
        val TAG = this::class.toString().split(".").last().dropLast(10)
    }
}
```

It's not the most elegant solution but it works.

`this::class.toString().split(".").last()` will give you `"com.stackoverflow.mypackage.MyClass$Companion"` so you need the `dropLast(10)` to remove `$Companion`.

Alternatively you can do this:

```
package com.stackoverflow.mypackage

class MyClass
{
    val TAG = this::class.simpleName
}
```

But then the `TAG` member variable is no longer "static" and doesn't follow the recommended naming conventions.

Comment: So much for Kotlin as a way to _reduce_ boiler-plate code!

Answer (score 1):

[AnkoLogger](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Commons-%E2%80%93-Logging)  uses an interface to define the log tag.

```
interface AnkoLogger {
            /**
             * The logger tag used in extension functions for the [AnkoLogger].
             * Note that the tag length should not be more than 23 symbols.
             */
            val loggerTag: String
                get() = getTag(javaClass)
        }
private fun getTag(clazz: Class<*>): String {
        val tag = clazz.simpleName
        return if (tag.length <= 23) {
            tag
        } else {
            tag.substring(0, 23)
        }
    }
inline fun AnkoLogger.info(message: () -> Any?) {
    val tag = loggerTag
    if (Log.isLoggable(tag, Log.INFO)) {
        Log.i(tag, message()?.toString() ?: "null")
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
class MyClass : AnkoLogger {
    fun someFun(){
       info("logging info")
    }
}
```

Maybe AnkoLogger can give you some ideas to implement a custom logging tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
companion object {
    val TAG = ClearCacheTask::class.java.simpleName as String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I prefer to use live template. In android studio you can duplicate "logd" template, rename it and change "TAG" to "javaClass.simpleName".

Now if you type "logc"(or whatever template name you have) it will generate the whole line including method name without polluting code with extensions, fields or static functions.

[image: settings]

[image: how to use]

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, the usual way to rename something is to right-click the name, select Refactor->Rename. So, I think it's fine to do something like this,

```
class MyClass {
    companion object {
        private const LOG_TAG = "MyClass"
    }
}
```

because if you rename the class `MyClass` like I described, then the IDE will suggest renaming your LOG_TAG String as well.

Ultimately there are pros and cons of using this method vs. other methods. Because LOG_TAG is a String, there's no need to import the kotlin-reflect.jar, as you would if you set `LOG_TAG` equal to `MyClass::class.simpleName`. Also because the variable is declared as a compile-time constant with the `const` keyword, the generated bytecode is smaller since it doesn't need to generate more hidden getters, as described in [this article](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/exploring-kotlins-hidden-costs-part-1-fbb9935d9b62).

Comment: Why not naming it simply just TAG? Do you typically have any other constant with TAG in name in any class?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my extension function in kotlin, just add it in your extensions file.

```
val Any.TAG: String
get() {
    return if (!javaClass.isAnonymousClass) {
        val name = javaClass.simpleName
        if (name.length <= 23 || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) name else
            name.substring(0, 23)// first 23 chars
    } else {
        val name = javaClass.name
        if (name.length <= 23 || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            name else name.substring(name.length - 23, name.length)// last 23 chars
    }
}
```

Then you can use TAG in any class like below:

```
Log.d(TAG, "country list")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have defined an interface, which defines TAG as a property with default getter implementation.
The interface can be either "implemented" by a class but also by its companion object:

```
//Prefix allows easier filtering in LogCat
private const val PREFIX = "somePrefix.";

interface HasLogTag {
    val TAG: String
        get() {
            val name = javaClass.canonicalName?.removeSuffix(".Companion")?.substringAfterLast(".")
            return "$PREFIX${name}"
        }
}
```

The interface is used as follows:

```
import yourPackage.HasLogTag     
....
class MyClass : HasLogTag {
    ...
    //Alternatively: Let the companion object "implement" the interface
    companion object : HasLogTag {
    ...
    Log.e(TAG, "Some Info)
}
```

As the getter is called on every usage, there is however no advantage in defining the TAG for the companion object.

Note: In a previous version, I used reflection to find out, whether the class itself or the companion object defines the interface.

This however seemed to slow down heavily the startup of my app.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a clear and efficient way to log content, but I ended up with using Timber. It's very useful and easy to use:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:5.0.1'
}
```

usage:

```
Timber.d("Simple Log")
```